# How can I assign a certain rank to a variable if certain conditions are met in R

Tags: r, if-statement, case

I have a variable (RANK) that I am trying to assign certain values to based on certain conditions. There are 13 possible ranks (1 being the most serious type of crime to  10 being the least serious, and 13 which is basically 'missing' and what I am trying to replace based on the crime committed)

I have made a set of rules using str_detect to indicate (True or False) if a certain string of text is included in the observation. I currently have 22 rules, but will be including more as I build out the code.

I have tried both case_when and If_else. However, I know that with case_when, it will take the first condition that matches meaning things need to be in a very particular order, which unfortunately I don't think will work for me. Example code below.

```
    cleaned_data<-dataset_toclean2 %>% mutate(
RANK=case_when(
  Murder==FALSE & sexoffense==FALSE & felony==TRUE & commonlaw==FALSE & kidnap==TRUE|FALSE  & robbery==TRUE|FALSE & rwdw==TRUE|FALSE & awdw==TRUE|FALSE & abuse==TRUE|FALSE & discharge==TRUE|FALSE|burglary==TRUE & second==FALSE~"5",
  secondmurder==TRUE~"3",
  Murder==TRUE & FirstDegree==TRUE|FALSE & conspir==TRUE|FALSE & attempt==TRUE|FALSE & access==TRUE|FALSE & aid==TRUE|FALSE & solic==TRUE|FALSE | mansla== TRUE|FALSE| Murder==TRUE~"2",
  sexoffense==TRUE~"4",
  TRUE ~ "13"
) )
```

However, when I view the cleaned_data, all of the 2's, 3's, and 4's are correct but the 5's only have a handful that are accurately changed. The rest of the observations that should be 5's remain as 13 (unranked) even though they fit my rules.

any suggestions would be really appreciated as I know it will get pretty unruly as I make more rules for the remaining ranks.

Comment: Just a minor type, `x == FALSE` is can be shortened to `!x` and `x == TRUE` can be shortened to `x`. So you could save a lot of typing with `RANK = case_when(!Murder & !sexoffense & felony & !commonlaw...`

Comment: And inspecting that line shows bad syntax: I assume by `kidnap==TRUE|FALSE` you mean `kidnap == TRUE | kidnap == FALSE`, which **cannot** be shortened to `kidnap == TRUE|FALSE`. You could use `kidnap %in% c(TRUE, FALSE)`. But you really should just leave out entirely if the value doesn't matter. (And similarly for the other `TRUE|FALSE` items).

Comment: If you need more help than that, please post a few rows of data that are misbehaving, and we can go from there. For example, use `dput(dataset_toclean2[c(1, 2, 5), ])` to make a copy/pasteable version of rows 1, 2, and 5, including all class and structure info.

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I am pretty new to R.  I can't give full examples as part of the data is confidential. Is there another way to show where the problems are? When I implemented some of your suggestions it also seems to take away all 4's and just leaves me with mainly 2's and 5's even where there shouldn't be. Basically I am trying to find a way that says if murder is not true and sex offense is not true but either kidnap or robbery or abuse or awdw is true then assign 5 and if sexoffense is true assign 4, and so on and so forth.

Comment: *"if murder is not true and sex offense is not true but either kidnap or robbery or abuse or awdw is true then assign 5"*: `!murder & !sexoffense & (kidnap | robbery | abuse | awdw) ~ "5"` (check my column names, of course)

Comment: But if you need more help, you'll need to find a way to share data. If you just share these columns that are TRUE or FALSE (no ID column or anything), and you only share 5 or 6 rows, it's extremely anonymized, so I would hope it would be shareable. Or make an example with fake data.